# Xero API Tax Rate Modified Since

Tags: xero-api

I'm attempting to filter the list of Tax Rates in Xero by the date since which it is modified. Unfortunately it does not seem to be working, even when using the "Modified After" filter in the API Previewer, as it seems to still be showing every record present.

Comment: show us your code, input, expected output and actual output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately UpdatedDateUTC is not exposed on the [TaxRates endpoint](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/tax-rates) thus it cannot be filtered by the If-Modified-Since header